# Creating a Descriptor in Bluetooth Framework VCL

Tags: delphi, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, vcl, bluetooth-gatt

I'm using Bluetooth Framework VCL for a Bluetooth LE project.
I have created a Characteristic like this:

```
  var
   Service: TwclGattLocalService;
   Params: TwclGattLocalCharacteristicParameters;
   Characteristic: TwclGattLocalCharacteristic;
  begin
   Uuid.ShortUuid := $FFF1;
   Params.Props := [cpReadable, cpNotifiable];
   Res := Service.AddCharacteristic(Uuid, Params, Characteristic);
   Service.AddDescriptor() ?????
```

I want to create a Descriptor for the Characteristic I created. But there is no method for that. I see read and write descriptor methods in Gatt client classes. But not in server/service or Characteristic classes.

```
var
   wclGattClient: TwclGattClient;
   Characteristic: TwclGattCharacteristic;
   FDescriptors: TwclGattDescriptors;
begin
   wclGattClient.ReadDescriptors(Characteristic, OpFlag, FDescriptors);
   wclGattClient.WriteDescriptorValue(Descriptor, val);
```

I cannot use the Delphi default BluetoothLE components because Gatt server functions are not implemented for Windows.

Comment: We have updated the library and now you can add Characteristic User Description and Characteristc Presentation Format descriptors if needed. You can download updated version from our site: https://www.btframework.com/bluetoothframework.htm

Answer (score 1):

Current version does not support descriptors for GATT server. Actually in most cases it is not required because Client Configuration Descriptor always created automatically for indicatable and notifiable characteristics. In case if you need other descriptor type contact us at support@btframework.com and we discuss this issue.

Comment: I'm developing a BLE server virtual keyboard in windows and I want to create a descriptor in this UUID:
$2908 (Report Reference)
The automatically created descriptor is not enough.
It doesn't wok without that descriptor in that UUID. 
Is that possible to do it using this components?

Comment: @user3431569 I think yes, we can do it. Contact us at support@btframework.com so we can add the task in our ToDo list.